# Types of property 'src' are incompatible in nextjs/image

Tags: typescript, next.js, nextjs-image

I am using react dropzone to upload multi-image in my simple application. For showing which type of images are drop for that I make a separate component with TypeScript. But Next.js image src is showing error like Type:

```
'{ src: string; alt: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ImageProps'.
  Type '{ src: string; alt: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectImageProps'.
    Types of property 'src' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'StaticImport'.
```

RenderFiles.ts:

```js
import { IFile } from "../../libs/types";
import { sizeInMb } from "../../libs/sizeInMb";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import Image from "next/image"

const RenderFile: FunctionComponent<{
  file: IFile;
}> = ({ file: { formate, sizeInBytes, name } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image src={`/images/${formate}.png`} alt="image"/>
      <span>{name}</span>
      <span>{sizeInMb(sizeInBytes)}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RenderFile;
```

types.ts:

```js
export interface IFile {
  name: string;
  sizeInBytes: number;
  formate: string | number;
  id?: string;
}
```

What is my mistake in src props?

Comment: are you loading the image from local path or any remote cdn?

Comment: if you are loading image locally then you should use `import image from "img/path";` & `<Image src={image} alt="something"`

Comment: no bro I m using API call for that...if the image was coming from locally that was so much easy.

Comment: adding a `width` and `height` props will solved it. you may also want to add `layout`.

Comment: if it is from remote api call then why are you using `/images/`? in your remote api response it should be a cdn link which will have a url. so it sould be `<Image src={url} />` something like this.

Comment: Having the same issue here.

Answer (score 15):

The issue is `next/image`'s `Image` is expecting rather complex type `ImageProps` as it's props:

```ts
type StringImageProps = {
  src: string
} & (
  | { width?: never; height?: never; layout: 'fill' }
  | {
      width: number | string
      height: number | string
      layout?: Exclude<LayoutValue, 'fill'>
    }
) &
  (
    | {
        placeholder?: Exclude<PlaceholderValue, 'blur'>
        blurDataURL?: never
      }
    | { placeholder: 'blur'; blurDataURL: string }
  )

type ObjectImageProps = {
  src: StaticImport
  width?: number | string
  height?: number | string
  layout?: LayoutValue
  placeholder?: PlaceholderValue
  blurDataURL?: never
}

export type ImageProps = Omit<
  JSX.IntrinsicElements['img'],
  'src' | 'srcSet' | 'ref' | 'width' | 'height' | 'loading' | 'style'
> & {
  loader?: ImageLoader
  quality?: number | string
  priority?: boolean
  loading?: LoadingValue
  unoptimized?: boolean
  objectFit?: ImgElementStyle['objectFit']
  objectPosition?: ImgElementStyle['objectPosition']
} & (StringImageProps | ObjectImageProps)
```

Since you're not importing image from local imports the only structure you're left is `StringImageProps`. To conform to it you have to provide one of the following props sets:

```ts
<Image src={string} layout="fill" />
// or
<Image src={string} width={number} height={number} /> // with optional `layout` prop but not of type 'fill'
```

both variants may be extended with optional `placeholder` (not of type 'blur') or required `placeholder: 'blur'` *and* `blurDataURL: string`.

And only after that you may provide native `image`'s attributes as `alt`.

Answer (score 8):

Importing the type for `ImageLoaderProps` solved the issue for me.

Example:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import type { ImageLoaderProps } from 'next/image';

const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }: ImageLoaderProps) => {
  return `https://example.com/?${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality}`;
};

export default function TestComponent(props: Record<string, string>) {
  const { imageResource } = props;
  return (
        <Image
          loader={myLoader}
          src={`/${imageResource}`}
          width="20%"
          height="20%"
        />
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I omitted `placeholder`, `blurDataURL` and `layout`. I also made explicity `src` as string. More info on this issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26735

Answer (score -2):

Just cast string as a any

```
<Image src={'string' as any} alt='Pic' />
```

Comment: I think the assumption is when a question around TypeScript is posed, OP is aware that casting as `any` is an option, but is looking for a strongly typed solution.

Comment: Well, it's true that casting solves the problem very easily ```<Image src={imgURL as string} alt={imgName as string} />```