# Why can't I pass a string to src in next/image?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have imported Image as follows: `import Image from "next/image";`

Error:

```
Type '{ src: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ImageProps'.
  Type '{ src: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectImageProps'.
    Types of property 'src' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'StaticImport'.ts(2322)
```

It seems like it will only accept an image that is imported even if the string I am passing into `src` is a local path.

**EDIT: Because it is a local path, how do I import it dynamically and then pass it into the image?**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68148204/types-of-property-src-are-incompatible-in-nextjs-image]

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `string` as `src`, you need to provide `height` and `width`
props as well

Example:

```
<Image
    src='/image.png'
    width={200}
    height={200}
 />
```